# Laravel - Populating view with info from single row (with pivot data)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I currently have a form/view that allows a `User` to save an `Order`. This also updates a pivot table with the respective `Product`s and `qty`s. What I am trying to do, is after this information is inputted and saved into the database, I want to send the user to a checkout page that shows all the information they inputted for that `Order`.

**Relationships**

`User hasMany Order`

`Order belongsToMany Product`

`Product belongsToMany Order`

**checkout.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($orders as $order)
  @foreach ($order->products as $product)
    <tr>
    <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->pivot->qty }}</td>
  </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**OrderController.php**

```
public function checkout($id)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->load("orders.products"); //eager load pivot table
    $orders = $user->orders->where('order_id', $id);

    return view('orders.checkout', compact('orders', 'user'));
}
```

I know I am calling the order incorrectly, because if I change

```
    $orders = $user->orders->where('order_id', $id);
```

to

```
    $orders = $user->orders;
```

It displays correctly, except of course, it populates with every `Order`'s detail.

Or is there some elegant way for me to pass the data from the `checkout` function without this additional query? (I understand about moving data in Sessions, but I am working with a pivot table, and that complicates things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on the checkout page, you want to use just the latest order that the user has made, then you can just load that order using [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding)

```
Route::get('checkout/{order}', 'OrdersController@checkout');
```

Then in your controller:

```
public function checkout(Order $order)
```

so from here, you can pass this order to the view, and list all the products from this order, and also in your `Order` model you should have a reference to the user that this order belongs to:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Accessing columns from the pivot table will be:

```
@foreach($order->products as $product)
    <div> {{ $product->pivot->column }} </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: With this setup I am receiving "Undefined variable: order". Do I still have to declare $order somehow?

Comment: you still need to pass the variable to the view:
`return view('orders.checkout', compact('order'));`